# Save a collection to page state in Windows 8?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have an app that loads webcomic images into a FlipView and I would like to save this in page state, however I seem to have run into some trouble with saving a List into LocalSettings. Is there a way for me to serialize this data so that I could save the state of my FlipView? Here's the code for Comic:

```
public class Comic
{
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Num { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public string News { get; set; }
    public string Safe_Title { get; set; }
    public string Transcript { get; set; }
    public string Alt { get; set; }
    public string Img { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Day { get; set; }

    public Comic() { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each element in [LocalSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings.aspx) has to be a supported [Window Runtime type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br205768.aspx) so you can't save the class instance itself, but you can create a composite value and set the individual properties. Take a look at the code sample for [ApplicationDataCompositeValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdatacompositevalue.aspx)

Alternatively, you could serialize to JSON and store as a single string (if < 8K total) or use a file in [LocalFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder.aspx) versus LocalSettings.

Comment: I've tried going with saving the collection as a JSON string, but for some reason it still won't save/load. I've followed the procedure here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh986968.aspx to the letter (changing LocalSettings to LocalFolder/File) but the data still won't load.

Comment: are you getting errrors?  If you're saving the string into a file, you'll be doing File IO (async), so [the sample here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465118.aspx#write_data_to_a_file) may be more germane

Comment: I haven't been getting any errors, it's just that the state won't save. I'm at 15/x items in my FlipView but if I try suspending and resuming the app I always end up back at 1/x.